# Download file without popup in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, popup, download

I am downloading a file using the code

```
btnDownloadTemplate.Attributes.Add( "onClick", "window.open('StudyReport/WordReportTemplate.doc', 'OpenTemplate', 'resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no');return false;" );
```

This will show a popup and the download dialog is shown. How can I avoid the popup and only the download dialog is on the screen?

Comment: I wrote an answer and all, but I have second thoughts, I'm not sure I get it... If you want something that downloads a file when you click on it, why can't you use a regular link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.
I remove the Attributes and add the click event and in it.

```
    string path = Server.MapPath("");
    path = path + @"\StudyReport\WordReportTemplate.doc";
    string name = Path.GetFileName( path );
    Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name );
    Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
    Response.WriteFile( path );
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Using Response.TransmitFile is more efficient than WriteFile, because it does not require the raw data to be buffered.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do a Window.Open, just change the URL of the page to be the document.

Answer (score 2):

A common trick is to open the link in an `<iframe>`. This doesn't require JavaScript, and won't open popups or blank tabs. The `<iframe>` can be very small, so it's almost invisible.

```
<iframe name="DownloadDummy">
</iframe>
```

And the link:

```
<a href="http://example.com/file.csv" target="DownloadDummy">Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can just use window.location instead of window.open.

var file = 'StudyReport/WordReportTemplate.doc';
window.location = file;

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [HttpResponse.WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) method?