# Control download of file in aspx pages with WebBrowser in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webbrowser-control

I'm facing with a problem, How can I automatically download a file with webbrowser in C#? I'm creating a automation tool, that makes a authentication on site and need to download a file on an aspx page, looking the action fired by the download in the chrome console button I can see the post data. My challenge is, download the file without open download dialog. Any suggestion of how handle post response? Or another way to do this stuff works?

**EDIT**

I'm using `HttpWebRequest` to make the `post` solicitation but when I handle the `Response` I only can see the html page instead of the attachment file. Using google chrome dev tools I receive the following information about the download file:

**Response headers**

```
Cache-Control:private
content-disposition:attachment; filename=numerosserieteste_D.txt
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Mon, 29 Feb 2016 13:25:53 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-UA-Compatible:IE=EmulateIE8
```

How can I use this information in my application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1295856/1129995

Answer (score 0):

use WebClient instead of WebBrowser:

```
using System.Net;



WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        client.DownloadFile("address of file", "local filename");
```

Comment: The authentication method is more complex than a simple user/pass type, I need to authenticate with an USB token, and select a user type, because of this I'm using the webbrowser because the user need to make a authentication, the rest of process is automatized, less the dowload.